# How to find the input queue(MQ) when we have a Message broker Flow

Tags: ibm-mq, mq, messagebroker

I have a deployed bar file in the MB in a execution group. Now i want to find out the input queue name from where the Broker flow is getting input.

PlatForm : AIX

Answer (score 1):

mqsireportproperties BROKER_NAME -e EXECUTION_GROUP_NAME -d AllMessageFlows -r

where:
BROKER_NAME is the name of your Broker (< version 9) / Integration Node (>= version 9),
EXECUTION_GROUP_NAME is the name of your execution group (< version 9) / Integration Server (>= version 9).

This will list all the properties associated with all the message flows, both deployed to the EG and in Applications (>= version 8).

To find the queue name you are interested in I suggest redirecting the output to a file and using vi or sed etc. to search for the string 'queueName' (case sensitive).

for example:
mqsireportproperties BROKER_NAME -e EXECUTION_GROUP_NAME -d AllMessageFlows -r | grep queueName

You will get back more than one line with 'queueName' in it. Some are internal queues that you don't need to worry about, some will be ones in flows you have deployed. In order to tell which one you want you will need to inspect the output.

The output lists the message flows directly on the execution group first and then the Applications. Under a tag 'Application' you will find the tag 'MessageFlow' and then the tag for the MQ Input node which will be 'ComIbmMQInputNode'. Under that you will find the 'queueName' parameter with the value you are looking for e.g. queueName='INPUT_QUEUE_NAME'. If you have more than one application you will have to find the one you are looking for, there is a 'label' parameter under each application which will be it's name. The same goes for message flows.

Comment: It should be "-o", at least for version 7: mqsireportproperties BROKER_NAME -e EXECUTION_GROUP_NAME -o AllMessageFlows -r

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are able to connect to remote brokers from your Windows machine.You can see the queues used by message flow via MB explorer. If you have **MB explorer** installed then just configure your broker and click on your flow. It will show you "Queues used" in the MQ explorer content.

**Alternatively**, you can also use **CMP API Excerciser** tool(Available in your MB installation directory under the folder named samples) as well if you don't have MB explorer.

Also, as CMP excerciser does it, you can write a **simple java app**, using MB API, and call **getQueues()** function through an object of your message flow.

I am not sure if a direct unix command is available for this purpose.